# How to insert Pandas dataframe into another Pandas dataframe without wrapping it in a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'x':100}])
df2[y] = [df1]
#df2.iloc[:,'y'].shape = (1,)
# type(df2.iloc[:,1][0]) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I want to make a df a column in an existing row. However Pandas wraps this df in a Series object so that I cannot access it with dot notation such as df2.y.a to get the value 1. Is there a way to make this not occur or is there some constraint on object type for df elements such that this is impossible?

the desired output is a df like:

```
         x           y
0       100          a  b
                  0  1  2
```

and type(df2.y) == pd.DataFrame

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: why dataframe? store it as a dict

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two DataFrame objects along the columns axis, which I think achieves what you're trying to. Let me know if this is what you're looking for

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'x':100}])

combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(combined_df)

   a  b    x
0  1  2  100
```

Comment: this is not it, the goal is to concat. i updated question to show desired result